# python image scraper, not working properly on bing

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, python-requests, bing

I am trying to build an image scraper, I first tried on Google but there is no image getting scraped
So I tried Bing and it worked, but there are some issues

1. Image links getting scraped are only a small amount of what is shown
   in the search engine.
2. **Scraped** images are from unknown page in the previews shown.
3. Images are by default getting **scraped** in Safe-Mode filter.

I wanted to scrape all the images(or some pages) that are shown in the bing.com/images/search
but instead it does very little of that.

After inspection I found that image links are stored in 'thumb' class in bing so I **scraped** all the links that had thumb class,
but looks like that isn't enough.

After looking through the source only thumb class links were found that actually had .jpg in the end

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import random
from urllib.parse import urljoin


url = "https://www.bing.com"

search = input("enter the search term: ")
r = requests.get(url + "/images/search", params={"q":search})

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

li = soup.find_all("a",class_="thumb")

# getting links from thumb class  

links = [l.get("href") for l in li]


print("{0} results found with the search term: {1}".format(len(links), search))
choice = input("Do You Want To Extract The Images? Y or N ")
dir_name = "Result"

# Creating the Result named directory if it didn't existed
if os.path.isdir(dir_name) == False:
    print("[+] Creating Directory Named '{0}'".format(dir_name))
    os.mkdir(dir_name)
    
n = 1
if(choice == 'Y' or choice == 'y'):
    for i in links:
        req = requests.get(i)

        #title = links[z].split("/")[-1]
        #there were some issues with the default titles so I instead used names generated by
        #random sequence

        print("[+] Extracting Image #",n)
        with open(("{0}/" + generateRandomSequence() + ".jpg").format(dir_name),"wb") as img:
            img.write(req.content)
        n += 1

  #for generating random sequence
def generateRandomSequence():
    seq = ""
    letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
               "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
                ]
    for i in range(0,5):
        seq = seq + random.choice(letters) + str(random.randrange(1,1000))
    
    return seq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a scrape for you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
seartext = input("enter the search term: ")
count = input("Enter the number of images you need:")
adlt = 'off' # can be set to 'moderate'
sear=seartext.strip()
sear=sear.replace(' ','+')
URL='https://bing.com/images/search?q=' + sear + '&safeSearch=' + adlt + '&count=' + count
print(URL)
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
results=[]
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
print(soup)
wow = soup.find_all('a',class_='iusc')
for i in wow:
    try:
        print(eval(i['m'])['murl'])
        print()
    except:
        pass
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-web-api-v5-reference#query-parameters) , you will find the query parameters for bing.

Comment: Great this worked, but It is still limited to 35 results, I tried to do offset even after including the offset parameter, the results are same and same images gets downloaded if the limit is more than 35

Comment: I tried offset as both integer and string but the result was no different

Comment: I believe the restriction of the 35 results is due to dynamic generation of the page. As the page is dynamically generated, you may need to use selenium

Comment: I incremented offset by 35 after every loop of scraping, this was written in the documentation of bing but it is not working

Comment: even we spoofed our user-agent. The page uses javascript. so requests and beautifulsoup has a disadvantage here

Comment: but bing doesn't say that "this works for requests and beautifulsoup"

Comment: yes, maybe its only for the people who use bing api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211543/discussion-between-aquib-shaikh-and-joshua-varghese).